# Pandas groupby on two column and create new column in excel based on result

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have excel file which i am reading in jupyter.

It has three column : 
1) *Webinar ID*: (66 unique value)
2) *Email*: email id of participants (which can log out in session and join again so duplicate email id for same webinar id)
3) *Time in session (minutes)*: participant present in session, since he might log out and again log in, there are multiple entries.

Code Used:
**data_group = data.groupby(['Webinar ID', 'Email'])**

**data_group['Time in Session (minutes)'].sum()**

I want to create new column in excel and store *Sum of Time in Session (minutes)* information for same - *Webinar ID and Email*

Thanks!!

Comment: what is *data['Session_Sum']*? TIA

Comment: Oh..  That is a mistake:  Use transform, try this: `data['Sum Session Minutes'] = data.groupby(['Webinar ID','Email'])['Time in Session (minutes)'].transform('sum')`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you wish to create a new column with the sum of times per webinar group and email.

Let's use `groupby` with `transform`:

```
data['Sum Session Minutes'] = (data.groupby(['Webinar ID','Email'])['Time in Session (minutes)']
                                   .transform('sum'))
```